# Ubuntu 16.04 Network Indicator shows wrong status

Tags: 16.04, network-manager, indicator

After fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 I am facing issues like Network indicator showing wrong status even though I have connected to dongle.

Sometimes it shows connected to LAN icon. What could be the solution for this type of problem?

Comment: As far as I understand, this is a longstanding bug and I too occasionally see it. I just do `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager.service` if I am sufficiently annoyed by the wrong icon.

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me I already tried.

Comment: Could you add output of `ifconfig -a` , `more /etc/network/interfaces /etc/network/interfaces.d/* /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/* /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`

Answer (score 1):

Try doing an `ifconfig` and if you have anything like `virbr0` among the network connections, that's the reason for the LAN icon.
That's a virtual network bride. If you're sure you don't need it, you can stop it or delete it permanently with the following commands:

```
sudo brctl delbr virbr0
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Comment: This is it! I accidentally left `wlp1s0mon` (monitor) running after using kismet so my indicator speeds were twice that of the actual speed. I used `sudo iw wlp1s0mon del` to delete the extra monitor device and my indicator speeds immediately reflected the change.